# Why did the data type of my DB change?

Tags: postgresql, aws, amazon-dms

I had PostgreSQL installation in an EC2 instance. I wanted to migrate to RDS and thus used the DMS service. However, I later came to realize that the data type of the columns have been changed. The changes in the datatype can be seen in the images attached.[image: table in EC2]

[image: table in RDS]

Comment: Seems jsonb were converted to varchar(765) and you lost the sequences (and perhaps indexes, have they been migrated?) It's probably a limitation of that DMS service. Have you checked its documentation?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I didn't find any such thing in their documentation. Have you encountered any such thing? Any references would be a great help.

Comment: How did you transfer your data? What versions were both dbs?

Answer (score 5):

The issue related to JSONB columns is a known limitation of DMS. In particular, if you're using DMS to migrate from your EC2 instance to RDS Postgres, it will convert the type to varchar(765) and truncate any JSONB column longer than 756 chars.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=735961

We heard during AWS Summit - San Francisco that the DMS team is planning a fix for this issue. For an update, please feel free to comment on the message itself.